# jQuery: Read data from json?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to get and display data (twitter feed) on my html page.

I have PHP page that connects to twitter API and creates this output:

```
[{
    "created_at": "Sun Apr 09 17:56:20 +0000 2017",
    "id": 851131679167139842,
    "id_str": "851131679167139842",
    "text": "hello world with an image goes here as a test! https:\/\/t.co\/jNfdESxPcn",
    "truncated": false,
    "entities": {
        "hashtags": [],
        "symbols": [],
        "user_mentions": [],
        "urls": [],
        "media": [{
            "id": 851131665623732225,
            "id_str": "851131665623732225",
            "indices": [47, 70],
            "media_url": "http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/C8_TvYqW0AEbBaP.jpg",
            "media_url_https": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/C8_TvYqW0AEbBaP.jpg",
            "url": "https:\/\/t.co\/jNfdESxPcn",
            "display_url": "pic.twitter.com\/jNfdESxPcn",
            "expanded_url": "https:\/\/twitter.com\/DavidHoperz\/status\/851131679167139842\/photo\/1",
            "type": "photo",
            "sizes": {
                "thumb": {
                    "w": 150,
                    "h": 150,
                    "resize": "crop"
                },
                "large": {
                    "w": 670,
                    "h": 728,
                    "resize": "fit"
                },
                "small": {
                    "w": 626,
                    "h": 680,
                    "resize": "fit"
                },
                "medium": {
                    "w": 670,
                    "h": 728,
                    "resize": "fit"
                }
            }
        }]
    },
    "extended_entities": {
        "media": [{
            "id": 851131665623732225,
            "id_str": "851131665623732225",
            "indices": [47, 70],
            "media_url": "http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/C8_TvYqW0AEbBaP.jpg",
            "media_url_https": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/C8_TvYqW0AEbBaP.jpg",
            "url": "https:\/\/t.co\/jNfdESxPcn",
            "display_url": "pic.twitter.com\/jNfdESxPcn",
            "expanded_url": "https:\/\/twitter.com\/DavidHoperz\/status\/851131679167139842\/photo\/1",
            "type": "photo",
            "sizes": {
                "thumb": {
                    "w": 150,
                    "h": 150,
                    "resize": "crop"
                },
                "large": {
                    "w": 670,
                    "h": 728,
                    "resize": "fit"
                },
                "small": {
                    "w": 626,
                    "h": 680,
                    "resize": "fit"
                },
                "medium": {
                    "w": 670,
                    "h": 728,
                    "resize": "fit"
                }
            }
        }]
    },
    "source": "\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter Web Client\u003c\/a\u003e",
    "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
    "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
    "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
    "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
    "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
    "user": {
        "id": 851119985732800513,
        "id_str": "851119985732800513",
        "name": "David",
        "screen_name": "DavidHoperz",
        "location": "",
        "description": "",
        "url": null,
        "entities": {
            "description": {
                "urls": []
            }
        },
        "protected": false,
        "followers_count": 0,
        "friends_count": 21,
        "listed_count": 0,
        "created_at": "Sun Apr 09 17:09:52 +0000 2017",
        "favourites_count": 0,
        "utc_offset": null,
        "time_zone": null,
        "geo_enabled": false,
        "verified": false,
        "statuses_count": 3,
        "lang": "en",
        "contributors_enabled": false,
        "is_translator": false,
        "is_translation_enabled": false,
        "profile_background_color": "F5F8FA",
        "profile_background_image_url": null,
        "profile_background_image_url_https": null,
        "profile_background_tile": false,
        "profile_image_url": "http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/851182210732494848\/lmgbNLvC_normal.jpg",
        "profile_image_url_https": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/851182210732494848\/lmgbNLvC_normal.jpg",
        "profile_link_color": "1DA1F2",
        "profile_sidebar_border_color": "C0DEED",
        "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "DDEEF6",
        "profile_text_color": "333333",
        "profile_use_background_image": true,
        "has_extended_profile": false,
        "default_profile": true,
        "default_profile_image": false,
        "following": false,
        "follow_request_sent": false,
        "notifications": false,
        "translator_type": "none"
    },
    "geo": null,
    "coordinates": null,
    "place": null,
    "contributors": null,
    "is_quote_status": false,
    "retweet_count": 0,
    "favorite_count": 0,
    "favorited": false,
    "retweeted": false,
    "possibly_sensitive": false,
    "lang": "en"
}, {
    "created_at": "Sun Apr 09 17:47:36 +0000 2017",
    "id": 851129482832470026,
    "id_str": "851129482832470026",
    "text": "How to display twitter posts using javascript https:\/\/t.co\/I49vjVbAUJ",
    "truncated": false,
    "entities": {
        "hashtags": [],
        "symbols": [],
        "user_mentions": [],
        "urls": [{
            "url": "https:\/\/t.co\/I49vjVbAUJ",
            "expanded_url": "https:\/\/www.script-tutorials.com\/how-to-display-twitter-posts-using-javascript\/",
            "display_url": "script-tutorials.com\/how-to-display\u2026",
            "indices": [46, 69]
        }]
    },
    "source": "\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter Web Client\u003c\/a\u003e",
    "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
    "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
    "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
    "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
    "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
    "user": {
        "id": 851119985732800513,
        "id_str": "851119985732800513",
        "name": "David",
        "screen_name": "DavidHoperz",
        "location": "",
        "description": "",
        "url": null,
        "entities": {
            "description": {
                "urls": []
            }
        },
        "protected": false,
        "followers_count": 0,
        "friends_count": 21,
        "listed_count": 0,
        "created_at": "Sun Apr 09 17:09:52 +0000 2017",
        "favourites_count": 0,
        "utc_offset": null,
        "time_zone": null,
        "geo_enabled": false,
        "verified": false,
        "statuses_count": 3,
        "lang": "en",
        "contributors_enabled": false,
        "is_translator": false,
        "is_translation_enabled": false,
        "profile_background_color": "F5F8FA",
        "profile_background_image_url": null,
        "profile_background_image_url_https": null,
        "profile_background_tile": false,
        "profile_image_url": "http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/851182210732494848\/lmgbNLvC_normal.jpg",
        "profile_image_url_https": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/851182210732494848\/lmgbNLvC_normal.jpg",
        "profile_link_color": "1DA1F2",
        "profile_sidebar_border_color": "C0DEED",
        "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "DDEEF6",
        "profile_text_color": "333333",
        "profile_use_background_image": true,
        "has_extended_profile": false,
        "default_profile": true,
        "default_profile_image": false,
        "following": false,
        "follow_request_sent": false,
        "notifications": false,
        "translator_type": "none"
    },
    "geo": null,
    "coordinates": null,
    "place": null,
    "contributors": null,
    "is_quote_status": false,
    "retweet_count": 2,
    "favorite_count": 1,
    "favorited": false,
    "retweeted": false,
    "possibly_sensitive": false,
    "lang": "en"
}, {
    "created_at": "Sun Apr 09 17:33:43 +0000 2017",
    "id": 851125986976567297,
    "id_str": "851125986976567297",
    "text": "Hello world",
    "truncated": false,
    "entities": {
        "hashtags": [],
        "symbols": [],
        "user_mentions": [],
        "urls": []
    },
    "source": "\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter Web Client\u003c\/a\u003e",
    "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
    "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
    "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
    "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
    "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
    "user": {
        "id": 851119985732800513,
        "id_str": "851119985732800513",
        "name": "David",
        "screen_name": "DavidHoperz",
        "location": "",
        "description": "",
        "url": null,
        "entities": {
            "description": {
                "urls": []
            }
        },
        "protected": false,
        "followers_count": 0,
        "friends_count": 21,
        "listed_count": 0,
        "created_at": "Sun Apr 09 17:09:52 +0000 2017",
        "favourites_count": 0,
        "utc_offset": null,
        "time_zone": null,
        "geo_enabled": false,
        "verified": false,
        "statuses_count": 3,
        "lang": "en",
        "contributors_enabled": false,
        "is_translator": false,
        "is_translation_enabled": false,
        "profile_background_color": "F5F8FA",
        "profile_background_image_url": null,
        "profile_background_image_url_https": null,
        "profile_background_tile": false,
        "profile_image_url": "http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/851182210732494848\/lmgbNLvC_normal.jpg",
        "profile_image_url_https": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/851182210732494848\/lmgbNLvC_normal.jpg",
        "profile_link_color": "1DA1F2",
        "profile_sidebar_border_color": "C0DEED",
        "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "DDEEF6",
        "profile_text_color": "333333",
        "profile_use_background_image": true,
        "has_extended_profile": false,
        "default_profile": true,
        "default_profile_image": false,
        "following": false,
        "follow_request_sent": false,
        "notifications": false,
        "translator_type": "none"
    },
    "geo": null,
    "coordinates": null,
    "place": null,
    "contributors": null,
    "is_quote_status": false,
    "retweet_count": 0,
    "favorite_count": 0,
    "favorited": false,
    "retweeted": false,
    "lang": "en"
}]
```

Now, I'm trying to use jQuery and AJAX/jsonp to read the data from that PHP page and display the twitter feed on my page.

So I did this:

```
    var poutput = $('#divTweets');

    $.ajax({
    url: 'config.php',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function(data, status){



            $.each(data, function(pi,item){ 
            str = item.id_str;  
                var products = '<div id="'+item.id_str+'" class="items">'+
                               '<p class="names">'+item.text+'</p>'+
                               '</div>';

                poutput.append(products);


});


},

        error: function(){
            //alert('There was an error loading the data.');
        }


});
```

However, when I run my code, I get nothing in my HTML Page. I did look in the console for errors and there was none.

Could someone please advice on this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of `jsonp: 'jsoncallback',` and set `dataType:'json'` not `'jsonp'`

You are returning json not jsonp.

Add error handling for further debugging

Comment: still nothing being displayed on my page!

Comment: does `success` fire? Have you inspected request in browser dev tools network to check status, response etc? Does `$('#divTweets');` exist when you declare `var poutput = $('#divTweets');`? You need to do some basic javascript debugging now and add error handling for feedback also

Comment: Yes, the `success` fires fine. I just put an `alert('fired');` inside the `success` function and it got fired. Also, yes, just double checked and the `#divTweets` exists too.

Comment: so put some logging inside `each` and see what `var products` produces ..if anything...process of elimination now

Comment: I have and it produces nothing.

Comment: so inspect `data` and `item`? And see if it is what you expect. You need to start narrowing down what is or isn't working right

Comment: OH WAIT, I just did `alert(products);` and it worked fine. so why doesn't it append it to the `#divTweets` ?

Comment: don't use `alert` for debugging......learn to use console. You are sure `poutput` is what you expect? Did you forget document.ready maybe?

Comment: I know how to use `console.log(products);` but alert is much easier lol

Comment: not for issues like this....you need to use more powerful tools.....console, debugger etc

Comment: agreed... but it seems to be working apart from not appending it to the divTweets